# LocalDateTime parsing error (Java 8)

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I'm reading a datetime from database in the format `2017-04-20 11:01:21.053`, which I need to parse to the format `04/20/2017 11:01:21`

I'm trying to parse this date on a LocalDateTime (Java 8) using the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateToFormat, formatter);
```

But I get the following error when trying to parse `2017-04-20 11:01:21.053`:

> Text '2017-04-20 11:01:21.053' could not be parsed at index 14

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: month ==> MM not mm

Comment: thank you! changing it give me this error though
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-04-20 07:48:10.807' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=807000, MilliOfSecond=807, SecondOfMinute=10, NanoOfSecond=807000000, MinuteOfHour=48, HourOfAmPm=7},ISO resolved to 2017-04-20 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your DateTimeFormatter to:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

[Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
   Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
   ------  -------                     ------------      -------
   y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
   M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J
   d       day-of-month                number            10
   h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)  number            12
   H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
   m       minute-of-hour              number            30
   s       second-of-minute            number            55
   S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
```

Comment: thanks... as above i now get this error ... java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-04-20 07:48:10.807' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=807000, MilliOfSecond=807, SecondOfMinute=10, NanoOfSecond=807000000, MinuteOfHour=48, HourOfAmPm=7},ISO resolved to 2017-04-20 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: You also have to change the hour part

Comment: Hour portion was failing because, since you were using `h`, you had to include somewhere on your date if that was AM/PM, otherwise the parser would have no way to guess that

Comment: thanks for the explanation, was in a rush to get something done and hadnt used this Java 8 feature before... much appreciated